# Fix node position based on another value in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed layout. The nodes are derived from json values which have the name,group as nodes and source,target and value as links. The json could carry the value 'size' as part of the node and I'd like to see if I can use this value to determine where the node is placed0 the idea being that the larger the size ,the higher on the canvas it would be placed.

I have two problems. a) I dont know if d3.js would render if the json carries extra elements on top of what is needed and b) I'm not sure how to change the y attribute based on this 'size' element.

The code I have tried out is:

```
     var width = 1400,
    height = 500

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-100)
    .linkDistance(130)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
    .append("g");


function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

var endpoint = window.location.href+".json"


d3.json(endpoint, function(graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("marker-end",  "url(#suit)");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.group; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
      .on('mouseout', UnconnectedNodes)
      .on("click",  function(d) { getprofile2(d); });

      function getprofile2(d){      
        $.ajax({
          url: "/graph/show", 
          type: "GET", 
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {name: d.name},
          success: function(result) {
            $('.bchart-content').html(result);
            addGraph(result);
          }
        });
      }


  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });


  //Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
var toggle = 0;
//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}



function connectedNodes() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        //Reduce the op
        toggle = 1;
    } else {
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        toggle = 0;
    }
}


function UnconnectedNodes() {
node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        toggle = 0;
}





graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph));
function threshold(thresh) {
    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(graph.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    node = node.data(graph.nodes);
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 5).call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}
});
```

but nothing really changes.

My data looks like this:

```
{  
   "nodes":[  
      {  
         "name":"Et",
         "group":5
         "size":14
      },
      {  
         "name":"Non Qui",
         "group":5,
         "size":19
      },
      {  
         "name":"Officiis",
         "group":1
         "size":13
      },
      {  
         "name":"Bilbo",
         "group":1
         "size":10
      }
   ],
 "links":[  
      {  
         "source":1,
         "target":2,
         "value":2
      },
      {  
         "source":1,
         "target":3,
         "value":1
      }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, what does your data look like?

Comment: I've added example data

Comment: See my comment on the @Alex_B answer is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/f6c38a2d0648233c503e) is an example of how to tweak the gravity function to produce the effect you are after.  I also added some shaking to help the diffusion...

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  padding = 0, // separation between nodes
  maxRadius = 12;

var n = 1000, // total number of nodes
  m = 10; // number of distinct layers

var color = d3.scale.category10()
  .domain(d3.range(m));

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(m))
  .rangePoints([height, 0], 1);

var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
    v = (i + 10) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
  return {
    radius: Math.sqrt(v) * maxRadius,
    color: color(i),
    cy: y(i)
  };
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .size([width, height])
  .gravity(0)
  .charge(0)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .call(force.drag);

function tick(e) {
  var a = e.alpha;
  circle
    .each(gravity(.2 * a))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return brownian(d.x, a);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return brownian(d.y, a);
    });
  force.alpha(a / 0.99 * 0.999)
}
var brownian = (function(w) {
  return function(x, a) {
    return x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * w * a
  }
})(10);
// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    //    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
          y = d.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK that's nice. But how would I add the 'size' field that I have as part of my json to dictate where the node should settle. This is different to the .size that is declared in var force

Comment: @SebastianZeki, you just need to get a number on to `d.cy` that is a function of `d.size` and scaled to fit in your chart y dimension. Then you can use the same gravity function in my example.  So, the scale would be st like `y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(maxSize)).rangePoints([height, 0], 1)` and then you can do `node.each(function(d, i) {d.cy = y(d.size)})`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data the code should look something like:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.size; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

the actual "cy" may also depend on the max height of your plot area so you may need to scale it accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will only be the starting value for cy, the layout dynamics and the code in the `force.tick()` callback will then control it. It's difficult to tell from the question, but I am guessing the OP is looking for a "layers" version of [multi foci force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919).

Comment: Hi Cool blue. Yes that is the kind of thing- preferably where the clustering is done according to size of the node (which is the extra field I added in the json data). I have put a fuller version of the script I am using. Presumably then var node sets the initial properties and force tick controls what happens next?

Comment: @SebastianZeki, yes and no... there is the `force.tick()` inside the d3 object and there is the custom callback that you provide, e.g. `myForce.tick(myCallBack)`. In the example I linked, the subsequent motion of the nodes is managed by the `gravity` function which is moving the nodes toward their respective `cx` and `cy` positions.  The velocity that this is being done at is a function of the internal alpha variable that is maintained by the force object under the hood.